# После загрузки канваса из json, объект перестал редактироваться

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Добрый день. Вот [ссылка на проект](https://jsfiddle.net/kenneb/zpo9aj7n/), такая проблема. При заполнении поля input появляется надпись на футболке. При нажатии кнопки see back , канвас преобразуется в json строку путем `JSON.stringify(canvas)`, затем очищаем канву `canvas.clear();` и затем грузиться обратная сторона футболки из json'a. При нажатии кнопки see front, происходит аналогичная операция. Затем когда снова пытаемся ввести, что нибудь в input, то создается новое текстовое поле.
Вопрос как сделать, что бы поле не создавалось, а редактировалось новое??